# 300% zoom: content center

Tags: html, css

i wanted my left right content be centered after zooming in 300% plus on the web page , i have tried so many ways, but still don't have an answer can anyone give me a hand here please.

copy and paste to make a new webpage, you can't see if you paste on fiddle or codewall.

**html:**

```
<body>
    <div id="lower_body">
        <h1>center content</h1>
        <div id="outer_warpper">
           <div id="outer">
               <div id="left"><h1>left</h1></div>    
               <div id="right"><h1>right</h1></div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

**CSS:**

```
#lower-body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#outer_warpper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#outer {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table;
    margin:0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#right { 
    width: 450px;
    height: 350px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: red;
}
#left{
    width: 450px;
    height: 350px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: grey;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
```

as you can see when it reach 300% or over (ctrl+mouse scroll), the left and right text is not in the center any more, because it push to left somehow

thank for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happened because you explicitly mentioned width: 450px. You should define the width either in % or you should try width <450

Comment: still cant ? can any one help me do it on fiddle? it still wont be center, any other way?